# nodetool removenode stuck during removal

Tags: cassandra

I have a small cluster that is virtually empty. Usually `nodetool removenode` completes in on the order of 10s of seconds. However, I currently have a node removal in process that is taking 10s of minutes and isn't seeming to make any progress. An additional request to remove the node is rejected because there is already a removal in progress. How can I troubleshoot this? For reference, here is the output to `nodetool status`:

```
Status=Up/Down
|/ State=Normal/Leaving/Joining/Moving
--  Address         Load       Tokens  Owns   Host ID                               Rack
DL  192.168.12.207  152.14 KB  256     32.2%  683d8351-c625-4d7f-99cc-61f6b73b0c56  rack1
UN  192.168.12.205  215.21 KB  256     37.2%  b66d5fff-ef1d-4fbf-a49a-43709df99a0c  rack1
UN  192.168.12.208  148.09 KB  256     30.6%  39b54771-59b8-49f7-8db8-9cf4523d6c8d  rack1
```

Also, cassandra is not running on host 207 (the leaving host), but is running on the other two hosts.

EDIT: It seems there is at least one token that is stuck awaiting replication:

```
$ nodetool removenode status
RemovalStatus: Removing token (-9037887679483580088). Waiting for replication confirmation from [/192.168.12.205].
```

Comment: Did you perform a nodetool repair first?

Comment: No, is that not optional? This has worked many times for me in the past despite not running nodetool repair without running into this issue. Why would this lead to sporadic failure?

Comment: BTW, these [instructions](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_remove_node_t.html), which suggest running `repair` followed by `decommission`, followed by `removenode`, do seem incorrect. Running `nodetool decommission` itself appears to remove the node, leaving `removenode` moot. I had opted to use a different sequence of steps that involved just running `removenode`, which also requires bringing cassandra down on the machine first.

Comment: I tried running `nodetool repair` and it seemed to block for a very long time (on the order of 10 minutes before I killed the repair for nearly empty freshly initialized cluster, with only a schema added), so I'd like to find a reliable solution that doesn't involve `nodetool repair` if possible.

Answer (score 16):

Don't know which version of Cassandra is the one with the problem. But, if **nodetool removenode** is not working, according to the [Apache Cassandra Wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/NodeTool), you should try the following:

> Removenode
>
> Removing a node that does not physically exist anymore is done in two
>   steps:
>
> ```
>   bin/nodetool removenode <UUID> 
>
>   bin/nodetool removenode force
> ```
>
> The first command will block forever if the computer attached to that UUID was
>   physically removed (or does not run Cassandra anymore). Just click
>   Ctrl-C after a second or two before running the second command.
>   Obviously, it is better to first decommission a node if possible or
>   you may lose some of your data.
>
> The "bin/nodetool status" command shows the UUID of your nodes.

Hope it helps .

Answer (score 1):

You are probably experiencing a known bug, [CASSANDRA-6542](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6542)